# Setting a new property on the isolate scope of a directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just upgraded to angularjs 1.2.1, and some code which has been working before, is no longer working.

I have the following directive:

```
var fooFactory = function($timeout)
{
    var foo = 
    {   
        scope:
        {
            bar: '=',
            baz: '=', 
            onBar: '&',
            onBaz: '&',
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', 
           function($scope, el, attrs)
           {
               var that = this;      
               that.state = null;
               that.main = function()
               {
                  that.state = "init";
               };

               that.getState = function()
               {
                   return that.state;
               }


              that.main();
              $scope.foo = that;    
              console.debug( "foo main called", $scope.foo );
           }],


       link: function(scope, el, attrs)
       {
       },

    };
    return foo;
};

MyAngularApp.directive('foo', ['$timeout', fooFactory]);
```

Here's how I'm including this directive in the view:

```
<div data-foo="true">
   Foo: {{foo}} <br />
   Foo state: {{foo.getState()}}
</div>
```

The problem is, when I run this code, I do get the console.debug statement for `foo main called()`, and `$scope.foo` is correctly set to the controller of the `foo` directive. But in the view itself, I see no output at all for either `{{foo}}` or `{{foo.getState()}}`, as if these have not been set on the scope at all.

Is it because of the isolate scope, that the line `$scope.foo = that;` is not having any effect? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works if you update (I would rather say pollute) the one already in the parent scope:

```
$scope.$parent.foo = that;    
console.debug( "foo main called", $scope.$parent.foo );
```

Weird! It seems instead of creating a model in the directive's scope it goes up the chain looking for the model in the parent scope which I believe is not even there.
Totally weird!

Comment: Can you explain the last sentence a bit?

Comment: @ClickUpvote I dont think you have `foo` in the parent scope. This means doing `$scope.foo = something` should create a model in the directive scope. But it does not. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Actually it seems to be because of the isolate scope. If I remove the isolate scope from the directive, then it works. Not sure if that's a feature or a bug.